# JPA retrieve entities relationships

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

I am trying to retrieve the list of all entities containing relations that references the specified entity.

**"Role" Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Role")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Role implements Serializable {
    private String description;
    private Long roleId;

    @Column(name = "role_id")
    @Id
    public Long getRoleId() {}

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescrition() {}
}
```

**"User" Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @Id
    public Long getUserId() {}

    @ManyToOne()
    JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    public Role getRole() {}

    public String getName() {}
}
```

**"Group" Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groups")
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class User implements Serializable {
    private Long groupId;
    private String description;
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    @Id
    public Long getGroupId() {}

    @ManyToOne()
    JoinColumn(name="role_id")
    public Role getRole() {}

    public String getDescription() {}
}
```

I need a that works like this :

```
List<Class<?>> entities = getEntityReferences(Role.class);
foreach (Class<?> entity : entities )
    System.out.println(entity.getName());
```

The output would be :

```
User
Group
```

I think JPA use something like this for the bean validations or cascade mechanics but I can't find a simple way to achieve this.

The only way I found by now is to iterate through all the annotations of all the entities (returned by `"entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel().getEntities()"`) to look for relations (`ManyToOne`, `OneToOne` ect.). It seems a bit tedious, I'm sure there's a better way to do it...

Thank you all...

Comment: Why do with that information exactly?

Comment: I will need to export the data from a table (variable) and all its dependancies, but the datamodel can be modified...

Comment: You could do that with reflection. Find all Classes with the annotation Entity and a ManyToOne annotatoin on a filed of type Role. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: And you need to do that in Java? Usually data base exports are mostly done with plain SQL.